# Why dead code in OpenCL kernel influence result in Nvidia GTX550ti?

Tags: memory, opencl, nvidia

I am using OpenCL dev software of Nvidia on GTX550ti graphics card, and encounter a strange problem. (I am freshman for OpenCL).

My kernel code is like this:

```
__kernel void kernel_name(...)
{
size_t d = get_local_id(0);
char abc[8];
...
}
```

Actually, the `char abc[8]` is useless (dead code) for my case. But, if I have the `char abc[8]` in my kernel code, the result will be totally messy and the running time of kernel will be much longer (2095712 ns). If I comment out the `char abc[8]`, the result becomes correct, and the running time of kernel becomes shorter (697856 ns). The compiler of kernel won't wipe off the dead code?

The above is just an explicit example that I can repeat. I also encounter more stranger case that one program gets different result when run at different time in totally the same environment.

Is that related to memory allocation or..? Anyone can give me some advice on how to find the problem?

By the way, oclDeviceQuery output information is listed as follows:
Platform Version = OpenCL 1.1
CUDA 4.2.1,
SDK Revision = 7027912

My OS is Windows XP.

Today is 2012-07-17, and I think I have resolved this problem.

1. don't use #include in kernel source file.
2. don't use ultra length line (for example, you write program to generate some line data for kernel source file) in kernel source file.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, that shouldn't effect anything.

That's not your real code though, and I suspect given those run-times that your kernel isn't a simple thing. Possibly you're pushing your locals over some limit which means that variables are having to be stored in some slower memory which pushes your run-times up.

Something like that might also cause a change in behaviour if you had an uninitialised variable bug somewhere. In the fast store it happens to get a value that works. In the slow store it gets something else.

To check this theory I'd try to remove some other local data structure and see if it has the same effect. Anything else 8 bytes or larger should have the same effect.

---

...of course it's possibly you've found a bug in the OpenCL implementation, but that's easy to check. Just compile the kernel for a different OpenCL device, e.g. the CPU. This is worth doing anyway because different compiler pick up different issues.

Other than that I think you're back to standard debug techniques.

---

BTW: at one point in your question you call the array `abs[8]` rather than `abc[8]`. I assume that's a typo, but if it isn't then that could be your problem as the `abs` name will clash with the `abs()` function. That could confuse a stupid compiler.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, my code run correctly on CPU with both intel and AMD OpenCL SDK. BTW, I do use abc[8], not abs[8] (you can check my question carefully). There isn't a typo.

Comment: You wrote: "If I comment out the "char abs[8]", the result becomes correct,". I've just edited it to correct it.

Comment: Oh, really. I am sorry. It is an typo. In my real code, it is abc[8]. Anyway this is very strange.

Comment: I have done more experiments, and I think the problem maybe is related to how read kernel file to string and how clCreateProgramWithSource process the string. I will try 2-D string instead of current 1-D string for representing kernel source code.

Comment: I have done some experiments on reading kernel file to string: like 2-D string instead of 1-D string. But the problem is still there. Now my colleagues and I tend to believe that the problem is related to barrier location and the inherent character of parallel execution (synchronization, lock, consistent, ...). There must be some loose constrain on synchronization in my code, and it causes different results every execution. It depends on some run-time situation of OS/computer environment.

Comment: Today is 2012-07-17, and I think I have resolved this problem.

1.don't use #include in kernel source file.

2.don't use ultra length line (for example, you write program to generate some line data for kernel source file) in kernel source file.